# how do i call a public method in a service from a class

Tags: android, android-service

If i have a timer task inlined in a Service Class and the Service class has a public method..  how can i call the public method in my service class from the TimerTask?

```
 class uiCheckTask extends TimerTask {
        Boolean secDialog = false;
        NavOverrideService myService;

        public void run() {
            try {
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processList = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

               String cProcess = processList.get(0).processName;

               if (!cProcess.equals("com.example.services_test") && !secDialog) {
                  // myService.launchSecurity(); /// HELP HERE!
               } else {

               }
            } catch(Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
```

launchSecuity:

```
public void launchSecurity(){
    Log.v("LAUNCHING", "((((((((((((((((((((SECURITY)))))))))))))))))");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecurityService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Instantiate the class and call the method?

Comment: i tried that,but i get a null point exception.. the service is already running and is what started the timerTask to begin with..

Comment: What does launchSecurity do?  Can it be static?

Comment: LaunchSecurity was trying to launch another Service or add a view to the existing windowManager

Comment: it firing but throwing a null pointer.. adding the method above

Comment: acj's answer is the way to call an outer class's method from an inner class.  Is uiCheckTask an inner class of your service, and have you tried what he proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `uiCheckTask` is an inner class of your `Service`, then you can call the public method via

```
(MyService.this).launchSecurity()
```

Please note that `MyService` is the class name of your service, not an instance or local variable.